# Free DNS server for Windows XP/Vista/Win7?

Tags: dns, subdomain, system-administration

I'm currently developing a security solution that should work across domains and as such I need a small private dns server to add various entries to. I could alter the hosts file to achieve the same result but since the hosts file doesn't support wildcard chars I will have a whole lot of entries, so a DNS server that supports wildcards would be a little bit easier. Any suggestions?

Comment: If he is building a software security solution and needs information about DNS then I think it is very related. It's just sad how many SO users are gaining rep and going on power trips.

Comment: It's really a shame that questions like this get closed. I don't have an answer for you, but you get an up vote from me for asking something i would not mind to learn.

Comment: Reopened, because of the +2 vote and the comments.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As a reference: http://sourceforge.net/projects/acrylic/

Acrylic is a local DNS proxy which improves the performance of your computer by caching the responses coming from your DNS servers.

I found it to work flawless on every Windows system from XP up to Win8, and it's open source.

And yes, it supports wildcards... it even supports regex for domain names.

Comment: This really should be accepted as the correct answer.  It's a free program and it's easy to configure.  Almost easier than dnsmasq, with the added benefit of shaving a milisecond off your dns response time.

Comment: @leeand00: I agree, and I just did mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

There is an XP version of [Bind](https://www.isc.org/software/bind), probably running as a Windows service.

Comment: this is not correct as Bind does not work properly on Vista and W7 from my experience if it does well to hard to configure correctly

Comment: The answer is quite old now so it may not be appropriate anymore.  That said, bind has evolved itself as well, haven't tried recently.

Comment: BIND is updated for Windows, https://www.isc.org/downloads/current, but it's quite annoying to configure IMHO. I avoid it even on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Microsoft DNS if you are using Windows Server (except Web edition). Or install a [Simple DNS Plus](http://www.simpledns.com/) trial (14 day) if you don't manage with BIND.

Answer (score 3):

Dual DHCP DNS Server is my favorite when it comes to forwarding domains to your computer. Also good to stop ads that runs on some programs. It also excepts wildcards and works on Windows 8.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/